# Google maps MarkerManager containsPoint() method use?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, markers, markermanager

i am using a marker Manager to display the markers on the map at different zoom level.. here i am displaying only the markers with in the bounds of the viewport when the user pans the map dynamically it sends ajax request and adds markers to the markermanager .It is working fine but what i want from marker manager is it should only allow us to push unique marker points to the markerManager class ...can anyone give me the suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with MarkManager but I'm pretty sure you can use the Proxy Pattern detailed here on the jQuery website http://docs.jquery.com/Types#Proxy%5FPattern so you can intercept calls to MarkManager functions

Comment: as i am using prototype in my project...can u suggest in this library?